# meetup for martialarts.stackexchange

Tags: discussion

The topic was brought up in the chatroom to have a meetup in NYC in July. It's rather short notice; is anyone interested in this happening? Is this even a good idea?

Can we make the argument that meetups are good / necessary / valuable for this SE over other SE ?

Comment: Is there anyone else in the NYC area?

Comment: As for other SEs: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/stack-overflow-meetups-april-6/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42539/local-stack-overflow-meetups It's a recognized SE practice. I brought it up off-schedule pportunistically because I'd be in NYC.

Comment: You could definitely make an argument for having one, but I wouldn't make comparisons of saying it's better for Martial Arts.SE than other Stack Exchange sites. Just do it and create value for this community and the people here.

Answer (score 2):

A meetup would be cool to host if enough people are interested in it. You can also invite other people or host it somewhere to try and get other people interested in the site.

What you plan to do is entirely up to you (or whoever is organizing it) and can range in the activities that you plan. The Stack Overflow meetups around the world have all done different things. You may want to consider presentations, talks, seminars, or just plain food and drinks. Your options are endless. Some of these ideas are highlighted around the [Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/).

If you have a proposal for what to do for a meetup, definitely bring it up and flesh it out.

Answer (score 1):

In-person interactions should, in nearly all cases, be valued more highly than internet-mediated interactions. Martial arts are no exception; in fact, they are a paragon example of the vast superiority of in-person communication.

I found the "Throwdowns" of bullshido.org to be the most valuable aspect of that martial arts website. Discussing things online is great, but when you meet physically, a whole bevy of better options arise:

- Trading technique with drastically reduced opportunity for miscommunication
- There is a great release of tension and building of camaraderie by sparring with people using our bodies instead of our words
- Putting a face to a name has been proven to make people nicer

I suggest piggybacking on an existing open mat in NYC so that nobody gets screwed if there's poor turnout.

Comment: Agreed, but what is the argument for this SE being different than other SE and benefiting from the meetups? The example you give, Bullshido, is a discussion forum, so the situation is different.

Comment: And I'd like to emphasize **sparring with people using our bodies instead of our words** -- If I'm sparring with people here, with words, I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: 1) I think all the SEs would benefit from meetups. 2) There's nothing wrong with sparring with bodies or with words. Iron sharpens iron.

Comment: And here I thought we were here to exchange information instead of trolling.

Comment: Sparring is not trolling. Sparring is the exchange of information. Often it's the most efficient method for doing so. The SE model is inherently competitive--between answers, between users, even between questions. It should remain benignly competitive. In as much as SE is both competitive and friendly, it is exactly similar to sparring.

Comment: Agreed with the allegory to the Bullshido "throwdowns". It's one of the few good things to come from that site, IMO. :) However, I can't make it in July, nor in NYC. I'll be elsewhere (in Massachusetts).

Comment: Its entire reason for existing is good too. At the very least it got more people thinking about whether a martial art would actually deliver on what it claimed to offer.